# How can I join multiple line segments and paths in Adobe Illustrator to create an overall shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, art, autocad

I often work with DXF files at work. Simple 2D shapes that are plotted then cut to manufacture products. Opening an Autocad PDF often results in segmented vector lines instead of creating one continuous line or shape. Is there a way to join multiple lines and points together to create one shape? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you looking for more than Object > Path > Join 

If you select both of the line segments, and then object>path>join. Should connect both of the line segments together.

Comment: Thank you @Lyssagal! I wasn't aware that the same action for joining points worked for line segments. :) I'm working on 15-16 CAD drawings that all need to be edited and fused together, so was looking for shortcuts. Thanks again!